# How to know the number of connected sockets in a given pool

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Everything in the title.

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.join('somepool');
  // Here I want to know how many socket's connections are opened in the given pool
  // Something like:
  io.in('somepool').length;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `io.sockets.clients('somepool')` to get all the clients connected and `io.sockets.clients('somepool').length` to get the number of connections.

Comment: `io.sockets.clients` is not a function